# In emmeans package, how to exclude certain uninteresting contrasts from pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, contrasts, lsmeans

Let's say I run the following contrast:

```
fit_robust <- lm_robust(feelings ~ treatment * condition, 
                 cluster = teamID,
                 se = "stata",
                 data = all_data)

rg = qdrg(object = fit_robust, data = all_data)
outgroup_means = emmeans(rg, ~ condition | treatment)
contrast(outgroup_means, method = "pairwise")
```

This yields the following results:

> outgroup_means

```
treatment = DD:
 condition      emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 Main_Treatment  0.565 0.947 398   -1.298     2.43
 Pure_Control    1.117 1.539 398   -1.908     4.14

treatment = DR:
 condition      emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 Main_Treatment  6.140 1.539 398    3.115     9.16
 Pure_Control    4.311 1.733 398    0.903     7.72

treatment = RD:
 condition      emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 Main_Treatment  6.783 2.492 398    1.885    11.68
 Pure_Control    1.154 0.852 398   -0.521     2.83

treatment = RR:
 condition      emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 Main_Treatment  0.722 0.804 398   -0.858     2.30
 Pure_Control    2.791 2.128 398   -1.393     6.97
```

> contrast

```
treatment = DD:
 contrast                      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Main_Treatment - Pure_Control   -0.552 1.81 398 -0.305  0.7602 

treatment = DR:
 contrast                      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Main_Treatment - Pure_Control    1.829 2.32 398  0.789  0.4305 

treatment = RD:
 contrast                      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Main_Treatment - Pure_Control    5.629 2.63 398  2.138  0.0332 

treatment = RR:
 contrast                      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Main_Treatment - Pure_Control   -2.069 2.27 398 -0.910  0.3636
```

Question 1. I'm not sure if a p-value correction is applied here, but I'm not interested in the contrasts involving `treatment = DD` or `treatment = RR`  How would I exclude them to ensure correct p-values?  I've seen examples involving specifying a custom grid, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Question 2. How would I specify the following contrast: `treatment = RD, Main_Treatment` vs. `treatment = RR, Pure_Control`; and `treatment = DR, Main_Treatment` vs. `treatment = DD, Pure_Control`?

For the second question, I have tried something like the following:

```
DD_control <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
DR_treatment <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

contrast(outgroup_means, method = list(DR_treatment - DD_control))
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Error in contrast.emmGrid(outgroup_means, method = list(DR_treatment -
>   :    Nonconforming number of contrast coefficients

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Question 1

As is documented, P-value correction is done by default separately for each `by` group. In this case, each `by` group has only one comparison, so there is no adjustment. You can always change the `by` group, e.g., to construct the comparisons for each treatment, then adjust as a single family of four comparisons:

```
summary(contrast(outgroup_means, "pairwise"), by = NULL)
```

You can also subset the comparisons:

```
summary(contrast(outgroup_means, "pairwise")[c(1,4)], adjust = "mvt")
```

[Notes: subsetting resets the `by` variable; also, trying `adjust = "tukey"` will fail be cause the Tukey adjustment applies to only *one* set of pairwise comparisons.]

#### Question 2

Here, you need to remove the `by` variable *before* computing the contrasts you want, because these are diagonal comparisons:

```
contrast(outgroup_means, 
    list(con1 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1), con2 = c(0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0)),
    by = NULL)
```

The order of contrast coefficients here is the same as the order of listing `outgroup_means`

You may find the [vignette on contrasts and comparisons](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html) useful.